# Workspace.RONisgreat1.InputController:58: attempt to index function with 'Update' -- I cannot seem to fix this bug

Tags: roblox

Here is my code (modulescript and InputController)

this is my 1st question so it might not be clear enough

-- this is module

```
function handler:Update(dt)
    if vm then
        vm.CFrame = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame
    end 
end
```

-- note - vm is the viewmodel

-- this is input controller

```
game:GetService("RunService").Stepped:Connect(weapon:Update())
```

The error is caused by the line of code above. I can't seem to find out what to do!

I have already tried RenderStepped, and weapon:Update, AND weapon.Update but that resulted in an error.

these are NOT tools, by the way

Comment: Heyo, we're gonna need to see more code, because your error is saying that `weapon` is a function and we don't have enough information to understand why.

Comment: Weapon is actually a modulescript

Comment: (module thingy) ```function handler.new(weapons)
 local self = {}


 return setmetatable(self,fpsMT)
end```   (inputcontroller) `local weps = game.ReplicatedStorage.Weapons:GetChildren()
local weapon = weaponHandler.new(weps)`

Comment: i already realized what the answer is but thanks